# How to change placeholder position by margin padding in Tailwind CSS?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css, placeholder

I want to change the position of placeholder text's position like `margin-left: 10px` and `padding-left: 4px` in Tailwind CSS.

```html
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="পুরাতন পাসওয়ার্ড দিন"  className=" placeholder-gray-500 placeholder-py-4 bg-red-400  focus:outline-none border rounded-xl h-12 w-160" />
```

Answer (score 5):

You can style the placeholder using the Tailwind `placeholder:` pseudo-class (see: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#placeholder-text ).

However, padding and margin settings don't seem to work directly on the placeholder even though classes like `placeholder:text-gray-500` will be applied. You could instead pad the input field (`pl-[14px]`), which is usually more appropriate since user-entered text will replace the placeholder.

```html
<input className="placeholder:text-gray-500 pl-[14px] focus:outline-none border border-gray-500 rounded-xl h-12 w-160" type="text" name="name" placeholder="পুরাতন পাসওয়ার্ড দিন" />
```

You can see and tweak a working example here: https://play.tailwindcss.com/v7HJ30jXga

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```css
@layer utilities {
  .placeholder-style::placeholder {
     padding: 5px 12px;
     margin: 5px;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="placeholder-style" />
```

Comment: where should i write this?

@layer utilities {
  .placeholder-style::placeholder {
     padding: 5px 12px;
     margin: 5px;
  }
}